# I'm having issues showing date in a textview and can't seem to get my activity's to close

Tags: android

I have searched online and a lot of forums but never got a solid answer on what is causing me the mentioned issues...There are a lot of HowTo's, and I've tried them but it never works...
I have 6 buttons on my main activity, each button starts a new activity. When I tap a button to go to the daily log activity, I have a text view sitting there that I want to populate with the current date. I have tried this this code in the on Create() method:

```
TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtCurrentDate);
String ct = DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(new Date());
tv.setText(ct);
```

This hasn't worked out for me.

For my second question...I have used the
     super.onStop();
     finish();

in a method for on Click event but then it crashes. Everywhere I have read says to do that but it doesn't work for me... What I want to have done is when I open another activity from my main activity there will be a button called "Save" that will do what database operations need to be done and close the activity and go back to the main activity. I'm using my galaxy s3 to run my apps instead of the Eclipse Emulator, incase that helps

Thanks

Comment: "This hasn't worked out for me." Does it crash if so post the stacktrace and some more relevant code.

Comment: Here is the main part of the logcat for closing the new activity...
07-03 01:26:26.149: W/dalvikvm(14235): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41c5f438)
07-03 01:26:26.159: E/AndroidRuntime(14235): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-03 01:26:26.159: E/AndroidRuntime(14235): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method CloseMyActivity(View) in the activity class com.example.startingnewactivity.MyNewActivity for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'button1'
I understand what the error is but I am sure I have done it correctly.

Comment: I'll have to post the code after my 6 hours is up, I'm a new member and can't post the code in the comment section because it is to long.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the Date, you don't say how it isn't working for you.. do you get no text or incorrectly formatted text?

As for exiting an activity.. I think you just want to call finish() on its own, don't call super.onStop().. calling the super.onStop() from inside a click event is going to cause you problems.

Comment: Wow, I am having such a hard time posting my code with my reply on here, keeps giving me errors

Comment: C James,
I figured it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use bellow code.

formatDateForPost(new Date());

public static String formatDateForPost(Date dateObj) {
        String date = "";
        try {
            SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            date = f.format(dateObj);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

```
    }
    return date;
}
```

Comment: nilesh, Thanks I got it figured out. I put my code into a method and called it from the onCreate method. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

here is the code I am using. I tried this morning removing the onstop method and it still hangs and crashes. The log cat shows that it can't find my Close Activity method but as you can see it is right there..

Nilesh Patel and C James.. as for the populating of the text view with current date, when I go to the new activity (where it should show the date) the text view disappears and nothing is there other than my background. Nilesh Patel, I'll try your code but its very similar to what I am doing.

Hopefully you guys will see what I am not seeing...
Here is my main activity code..
package com.example.startingnewactivity;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
public void startMyNewActivity (View view)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyNewActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

}

and here is my new activity code...

```
package com.example.startingnewactivity;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
```

import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

```
public class MyNewActivity extends Activity {
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_new);
    // Show the Up button in the action bar.
    setupActionBar();
}

/**
 * Set up the {@link android.app.ActionBar}, if the API is available.
 */
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
private void setupActionBar() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.my_new, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        // This ID represents the Home or Up button. In the case of this
        // activity, the Up button is shown. Use NavUtils to allow users
        // to navigate up one level in the application structure. For
        // more details, see the Navigation pattern on Android Design:
        //
        // http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html#up-vs-                              //back
        //
        NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
protected void CloseMyActivity() {
    super.onStop();
    finish();

}
```

}

Comment: Wow, am I ever an idiot! I just noticed why my method wasn't working...I set it as protected and not public. Even with the logcat pointing at the error, I just couldn't see it. I assumed when I saw the p that I used public and not anything else. Talk about dropping the ball...